# Vue.js 2 Watch not work on props updates from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i've tried to `watch` my props. The purpose is, i want to get `newValue` and `oldValue` from this props, but its not work as usual. Is it because the props change in another component?? causing `watch` to malfunction?

so this is my props

```
countryId: { type: String, default: "" }
```

this is my `watch` props

```
watch: {
  countryId: function(newCountry, oldCountry) {
    console.log("New => ", newCountry, "Old => ", oldCountry)
  }
}
```

and this is where the props value is obtained

```
SearchCountry(
  :countryId="(country ? country.country_code : '')"
  :key="(country ? country.country_code : '')"
)
```

and i was tried like this.. its work, but its just return `newValue`

```
watch: {
   countryId: {
     deep: true,
     immediate: true,
     handler: function(newCountry, oldCountry) {
       console.log("New => ", newCountry, "Old => ", oldCountry)
     }
   }
},
```

from console `New =>  GQ Old =>  undefined`

Comment: From what I see it should work, have you tried using Vue debugger tool to check whether the props really changed? If the prop is a string, the watch function should be simple as this without needing `deep`.

Comment: @マークさん it was, but it just return `newValue`

Comment: Can you double confirm that `countryId` really changed in the component? You can test by actually rendering the value out in the component, or use Vue debugger tool. 

'it just return newValue' I think it's because you added `immediate: true` and the first compare was fired immediately by comparing with default value

Comment: Hi@マークさん , yes i was test it, i tried to show on label and its show as well, but not for watch one

Comment: and if i not using `immediate: true` its not showing anything

Comment: The code looks fine and should fire whenever the `this.countryId` value updates (once the component is mounted - thus `oldValue` will be `undefined` if you tell the watcher to fire immediately.  Though I wonder what you're trying to do with the watcher (once you've compared old and new values).

Comment: How do you modify `countryId` from another component?

Comment: Hi @RuslanIsay yes its work fine if i modificated manualy, its update from vue multiselect, which generate `countryId` by selected country